# How manage properly network signal on IONIC?

Tags: cordova, typescript, networking, ionic-framework

i'm developing a web on Ionic implementing some tabs and webviews.

I'm using the [Cordova Network](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network/) plugin

I have created a function that has a listener in case there is no connection, in the main tabs page:

```
  ionViewDidEnter()
{
let disconnectSubscription = this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
  let vm = this;
  if(!vm.alertPresented) {
    vm.alertPresented = true;
    vm.alert.create({
      title: "Warning",
      subTitle: "Check your connection.",
      buttons: [{
        text: 'OK',
        handler: () => {
          vm.alertPresented = false;
          this.navCtrl.push(OfflinePage);
        }
      }],
    }).present();
  }
});
}
```

this works fine but I do not know how to control that a connection is slow, or that it is of poor quality ... I know that this could be looked at this way:

```
downlinkMax
Downlink Max Speed

Returns: string
```

But I don't know where to put it really, or with which element should be associated, or which is the threshold where the quality of a signal is good or bad.

I want to avoid the iframe crashes due a bad connection

Somebody could help me? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use the `onChange()` Observable of the plugin and then check which `type` of connection currently is available:

```
this.network.onChange().subscribe(() => {
  switch (this.network.type) {
    case '2g':
      console.log('probably not very fast ...');
      break;
    case 'wifi':
      console.log('wohoo wifi ...');
      break;
  }
});
```

But keep in mind that although a user currently has `wifi` connection it can always happen that there are some kind of network issues. Thats why you should also consider timeout-errors for your requests.
Angular makes this a quite easy task:

```
this.http.get(...)
   .retryWhen(error => error.delay(2000)) // if an error happens, wait 2 secs and try again
   .timeout(6000) // no success after 3 retries (6 secs), throw a timeout-error
   .map((res: Response) => res.json()) // everything went fine
   .catch(yourErrorFunction()) // do something with the error
   .subscribe()
```

Comment: I haven't too experience with angular... I can execute that function only on http or when? Thanks for your comment. I'll try that

Comment: You have to import `Http` from `@angular/http` and then you have to inject it in your constructor like that: `constructor(private http: Http) {}` after that you can access the http instance via `this.http`. But I'm sure the internet is full of great tutorials on that topic.

Comment: Yes i used before the http on ionic.. my question was about do something similar but relationed with the connection.

Comment: You can't set a timeout for the internet connection of your device if thats what you're asking. You have to request data via a request from somewhere so you can define when it should stop trying. Imagine your device is connected to wifi but there is some problem with you ISP and the connection does not work, the only way of knowing that is to try to load some data. If there is no response within a certain time (and you are sure the server is working) there is probably something wrong with the internet connection.

Comment: wow.. thast's a good one. I'll do the question as solved. What can i check? (some service who always is turned on). Thanks

Comment: It's probably not a good practice to constantly check some web-service just to ensure you have a working connection. Use it for your own requests, if one of them fails you display a toast/alert for the user to notify him that the request was not successful and he should make sure he is connected to the internet.

Comment: Yeah but i need to have an listener to check if network is disconnected because all of the content it depends of that.

Comment: You can use your onDisconnect() subscription for that, but it will only fire if the phone _knows_ it has no connection (e.g. no service, flightmode). If you have some kind of "ghost" connection like I explained earlier this will not do anything. You will never be a 100% sure your application has a working connection available that is one of many things you as an app developer need to manage when desiging your application.

Answer (score 0):

In addition i can do this:

Take a variable networkAvailable = false;.

Later in my JavaScript, detect network status using cordova-plugin-network-information and set the networkAvailable variabel to true.
This way user won’t see broken contents.